# Construct a $2022\times 2022$ matrix $A$ such that $A^{2022}=0$ but $A^{2021} \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

I want to construct a $2022\times 2022$ matrix $A$ such that $A^{2022}=0$ but $A^{2021} \neq 0$. More generally, I want to know how to construct a $n\times n$ matrix  $A$ such that $A^n=0$ but $A^{n-1} \neq 0$. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint. Try to answer your question for $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Consider the shift-up or shift-down matrices.

Comment: You want a matrix with minimal polynomial $z^{2022}$. Heard of Jordan Normal Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such matrix is $A=(a_{ij})$ where
$$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} 
      0 & j\neq i+1\\
      1 & j=i+1
   \end{cases}$$

Comment: "The" required matrix would mean unicity...

Comment: @JeanMarie fine now?

Answer (score 2):

The matrix with zeros in leading diagonal, ones in the super diagonal and zeros elsewhere is the matrix you want.

Comment: Or sub diagonal works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

$A=(a_{ij})$, where
$a_{ij}=0$, unless $j=i+1$, in which case $a_{i,i+1}=1$.